# Is Google maps only displayed with png images?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I wanted to know how Google Maps was working in the browser and I saw that :

- The map is divided in div's of 256x256 px's.
- When moving on the map it is requesting png/images. Very little additional data is received in a separate response for each image. (I didn't saw anything missing in the images)
- It is adding canvas elements for drawing markers, circle, lines,...

I thought Google Maps was only receiving data, that was then drawed with canvas in the browser.
Is it correct Maps is about png/images?

This would imply image they make available are rendered/updated upstream with the data they collect?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  As far as I understand it the server produces/generates png tiles, with the data drawn on it, and they send it to the client (so it comes in your cache ... )

Comment: For rendering, image is a winner against canvas. Less CPU needed, faster. The amount of data transfer seems bigger with images though... But indeed, if you cache all images, it might become a winner for the amount of data transfer too.

Comment: If you read the [Image Formats](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#ImageFormats) docs in Google Maps, you will know that 'png' is the default format but not necessarily the only image type. Images may be returned in several common web graphics formats: GIF, JPEG and PNG. Most JPEG images are progressive, meaning that they load a coarser image earlier and refine the image resolution as more data arrives. This allows images to be loaded quickly in webpages and is the most widespread use of JPEG currently.